# UICollectionViewCell рандомное выделение

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

Имеется кастомная ячейка. При нажатии на ячейку, цвет ячейки изменяется на синий

```
extension MyCell {

func markToSelect() {
    let myBlueColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 119/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.9)
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = myBlueColor

}
```

На основном View данные берутся из массива, где хранится информация с текстом ячейки и пометкой выделена она или нет.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellId = "CellId"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    let element = massive[indexPath.row]

    if element.isSelected == true {
        cell.markToSelect()
    }


    return cell
}
```

После нажатия на ячейку ставится пометка и цвет ячейки меняется на синий

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let element = massive[indexPath.row]

    //помечаем выделение
    element.isSelected = true
    cell.markToSelect()    

}
```

До этого этапа всё хорошо.
Сброс всех ячеек:

```
func reloadView() {

    //Cбрасываем значения
    for element in massive{
        if element.isSelected == true {
            element.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Вот тут начинается непонятная мне магия.
Выделяю одну ячейку. Она окрашивается в синий цвет. После того сбрасываю все ячейки и ожидаю, что все станут опять белые, но другая ячейка становится синей и т.д. Очистка не происходит, а рандомная ячейка становится синей. Если выбрать несколько, то несколько будут менять цвета.
Пробовал дебажить, вызова markToSelect() не происходит, но рандомная ячейка окрашивается в синий при этом текст сохраняется верный. Проблема именно с цветом.

Comment: Понял в чём дело... Я так понимаю, что ячейки просто используются повторно. Так что приходиться сбрасывать ячейку и всё работает хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще лучше организовать кастомный класс ячейки и не делать метод для выделения, а завести свойство в кастомной ячейке, которое само все выполнит

```
var selected: Bool = false { 
    didSet {

let selectedColor = selected ? UIColor(selected RGB) : UIColor(unselected RGB)
self.contentView.backgroundColor = selectedColor
    }
}
```

Использование

```
cell.selected = true
```

Тогда это будет явное использование, а не расширение функционала ячейки

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете пользоваться уже готовыми возможностями, которые идут "в комплекте" с `UICollectionView`

1 Множественное выделение:

```
collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

2 Настраиваем ячейку:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet(newValue) {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = .red //Цвет выделенной ячейки
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .white //Цвет не выделенной
            }
        }
    }
    //Вот здесь необходимо сбрасывать внешний вид ячейки
    //которая будет переиспользоваться.
    //Метод вызывается только при переиспользовании ячейки
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        isSelected = false
        //обнулить текст, установить placeholder image и т.п., все что необходимо для приведения ячейки в исходное состояние.
    }
}
```

3 Получаем все выделенные ячейки когда нам необходимо:

```
collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems
```